# Why doesn't this function work? (Linked list)

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

Can someone help me understand why this is giving me segmentation fault? The function is supposed to add n at the end of the list.

```
    typedef struct lligada {
    int valor;
    struct lligada *prox;
} *LInt;

void appendL (LInt *l, int n){
    LInt new=(LInt)malloc(sizeof(struct lligada));
    while ((*l) && (*l)->prox) l=&((*l)->prox);
    (*l)->prox=new;
    new->valor=n;
    new->prox=NULL;
}
```

Comment: NOw is a good time to learn how to debug a program.  Please read [ask], and post a [mcve]

Comment: Don't cast `malloc()`; don't hide pointers behind typedefs.

Comment: `struct lligada *head = NULL; appendL(&head, 42)` will crash. Can you see why?

Comment: There is plenty of links in the internet showing how to manipulate a list : [Example](https://harithimanshu.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/appending-nodes-in-linkedlist-c-program/)

Comment: @melpomene I don't have a choice but to use that definition of struct lligada, it is from an exercise. And i don't understand why it crashes...

Comment: This is might not matter, but I wouldn't name your variable `new` even if's legal in C

Comment: @Novaterata can you explain why? Is it a code malpractice?

Comment: `new` is an operator in C++ and a keyword in most C influenced languages.  That's why it's highlighted blue here. It's probably fine, but I thought I'd give you a heads up.

Comment: @Michael similarly naming a variable `this`. Try to avoid using names that are keywords in other languages. You can use more informative names such as `new_node`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If initially the head node is equal to `NULL` then this statemenet

```
(*l)->prox=new;
```

gives you the segmentation fault.

A more correct function definition can look like

```
void appendL ( LInt *l, int n )
{
    LInt new = (LInt)malloc(sizeof(struct lligada));
    new->valor = n;
    new->prox = NULL;

    while ( *l != NULL ) l = &( *l )->prox;

    *l = new;
}
```

Comment: @KevinDTimm  The word new is not a keyword in C though it is better not to use it because it is a keyword in C++. As for casting then it is just an advice of low-qualified programmers that repeat this foolishness one after another. I already down-voted the answer about the casting.

Comment: Yes, the constant refrain of "don't cast malloc" is silly, but I wouldn't call it "wrong". It's something akin to telling someone not to use single-pane windows when his real problem is that the house doesn't have a roof. True, but utterly irrelevant and inconsequential.

Comment: @KevinDTimm Please do not repeat this foolishness. All compilers report that the required header is absent. However  without casting you indeed can mask an error that is difficult to find.